# Web service para java desktop

Tags: java, aplicação-web, jersey

Tenho uma dúvida. Como é feita a requisição para uma página php utilizando java desktop? Devo criar outro projeto para java web?

Comment: Você quer fazer a requisição de dentro de um sistema desktop para um web ou o contrário?

Comment: Exato. Tenho um sistema desktop, que é um programa de vendas, e preciso enviar as informações para uma página php através do POST. Mas não estou conseguindo realizar essa operação.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode  utilizar  [java.net.HttpUrlConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)

Exemplo:

```
try {
        String urlParameters  = "param1=a&param2=b&param3=c";
        byte[] postData       = urlParameters.getBytes( StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );
        int    postDataLength = postData.length;
        String request        = "http://example.com/index.php";
        URL    url            = new URL( request );
        HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();           
        conn.setDoOutput( true );
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );
        conn.setRequestMethod( "POST" );
        conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
        conn.setRequestProperty( "charset", "utf-8");
        conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", Integer.toString( postDataLength ));
        conn.setUseCaches( false );
        try( DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream())) {
            wr.write( postData );
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Também não consegui. Só uma dúvida em urlParameters tenho que colocar a String que o POST solicitará? Eu fiz dessa forma: String input =  "{\"operacao\":\"cadastro\",\"tipo\":\"representante\",\"nome\":\"admin\"}";

Comment: Atualizei o exemplo

Comment: Mesmo assim,não funciona.

Comment: Mas o que acontece, aparece algum erro ? Ele chega a executar o request?

Comment: Vou mostrar o código que fiz para a requisição. Na página php, ele verifica se realmente existe algo no método isset. Caso não possua nenhuma informação, entra no else e aparece que nenhum dado foi enviado. Mas o estranho é que colocar System.out.println aparecer os dados.

Comment: Client c = Client.create();
            WebResource wb = c.resource("http://localhost:9090/nasu/teste.php");
            String input;
            String output;

            input = "{\"operacao\":\"cadastro\",\"tipo\":\"representante\",\"nome\":\"admin\"}";
            
            System.out.println(input);
            ClientResponse response = wb.type("application/json").post(ClientResponse.class, input);
                     
            output = response.getEntity(String.class);
            System.out.println(output);
            response.close();

Comment: Veja no exemplo a parte dos parametros "  String urlParameters  = "param1=a&param2=b&param3=c";"

Comment: Preenchi os campos dessa forma: operacao=cadastro&tipo=representante&nome=admin

Comment: Mas não aparece nenhum mensagem

Comment: No php você esta capturando os parâmetros com $_POST?

Comment: Sim. Está dessa forma:     if(isset($_POST['operacao'))

Comment: Se entra na condição captura os dados, senão aparece a mensagem de dados não enviado.

Comment: Mas ele chega submeter, só não envia os dados?